# Where do I program a variable in an objective c class so all its methods can use it?

Tags: objective-c, class, variables

I need to have 5 of my methods use a common variable, but I don't know where to declare it in my .m file. I know this is basic, but I'm quite new and I forgot where to put it. Please help me.

Comment: you want to create a private member in .m or a public/global ?

Comment: Please read a tutorial on Objective-C.

Answer (score 3):

```
@implementation {
    // instance variables here  <---
    int foo
    float bar;
}

// methods here

@end
```

Comment: Ah Shoot. Forgot about that. Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When someone answers your question, you should accept it. Please [read about accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).